# If $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2\}$, can I conclude that $\overline{A} \subseteq B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given two sets, $A$ and $B$, both contained in $E$:

If $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2\}$, can I conclude that $\overline{A} \subseteq B$?

Comment: What is $E$? What do you mean by $\overline A$?

Comment: \overline{A} is the topological closure of A?

Comment: Most likely $\overline A=E\setminus A$.

Comment: @Tomas: That’s my guess, too — which makes knowledge of $E$ crucial!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Hm... I fear that the exercise doesn't mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $E$ be the set $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Wait, $A \in E$ and $B \in E$, so you mean $E = \{A,B,1,2,3\}$?

Comment: I mean $\{1,2,3\}$. Then $\bar{A}=\{2,3\}$, which is not a subset of $B$. Note that $A$ is not an **element** of $E$.

Comment: Why isn't $A$ an element of $E$? I mean, the exercise says that $A$ and $B$ are contained in $E$.

Comment: We say that a set $X$ is contained in $Y$ if $X\subseteq Y$. The set of even integers is contained in the set of integers.

Comment: Oh.... OH.... My bad english strikes again. Ah, thank you, this would've been awful for all the other exercises.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: How do I break out of the ambiguity?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: I found $E = \{A,B,1,2,3\}$ fairly reasonable :(

Comment: You can always use the $E$ that you suggested, throwing in elements $A$ and $B$. Then whatever interpretation is takem, the counterexample will work. It will look a little strange, so you will have to explain.